# Detect Unicode in string and transform it to string character?

Tags: javascript, unicode

I got a string representing an email like this one:

```
info\u0040tartaytantas.es
```

Where `\u0040` is actually a `@` character represented like that instead of `@`, I was wondering if there is a way to parse a string, detect any non-well-formatted Unicode characters and change them to their good string representation?

Comment: `console.log('info\u0040tartaytantas.es')` outputs `'info@tartaytantas.es'`

Comment: I'm not getting back this result

Comment: Why not try it in the browser? What result are you getting?

Comment: FWIW, all **char** values in Java are Unicode.  'A' for example is a Unicode character '\u0041', and both representations are acceptable in Java.

Comment: How does `\u0040` get there in the first place? A reason I can think is that you actually have JSON at some point, but fail to decode it properly. I think it's easier to avoid data corruption than to fix it afterwards.

Comment: Agree with @ÁlvaroGonzález. You might be looking for ``const val = 'info\\u0040tartaytantas.es'; JSON.parse(`"${val}"`)``

Comment: @user14387228 Java?

Comment: Oops. Usually I filter on tag=java; I failed to notice the filter was off.